# Argparse скрипт не работает

Tags: python, argparse

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='подсчет колличества очков по строке с результатом')
parser.add_argument("--a", "--argument", help='строка с результатом игры')
args = parser.parse_args()

result = args.a
print('Количество очков для результатов', result, '-', get_score(game_result=result))
```

Я сделал вот такой код. В терминале прохожу до нужной папки где лежит файл с модом. Потом прописываю `python --a='Строка'`, и получаю сообщение, что команда не найдена. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Понял, в чем проблема. В документации из сети было указано вначале ставить python, но по факту должен указываться python3